# How to install prerequisites for running setup.py in setuptools?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

`setuptools.setup` offers its `install_requires` argument. Specified packages are installed  at the end of `setup.py`. It seems like there're other requirements sections as well (`tests_require` and `requirements`). I didn't find any info on the latter because `help(setuptools.setup)` doesn't contain any useful information about it's arguments. I checked the source of `distutils.Distribution` `distutils/dist.py`, but it doesn't contain useful documentation (one might say - at all).

I know that setuptools isn't self-bootstrapping (like e.g. maven). It just want to make sure I'm not missing something.

I can imagine straightforward workarounds like installating with `pip` and `subprocress.*` functions. I'm looking for a declarative solution.

Comment: Maybe what you need is the `setup_requires` parameter: https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html

Comment: Yes, that's perfect. And there's a list of `setuptools.setup` parameters. I'm searching for this since ages. You can post this as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe what you need is the `setup_requires` parameter: [Building and Distributing Packages with Setuptools](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html)